# Optimise R loop with data table passed into a recursive function

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, data.table

I'm trying to run a simulation which would run n_tests for n_products for n_years to estimate an increase in demand and subsequent increase in stored pallets (linear relation between demand and stored products assumed). To make things a bit spicier, the demand comes from 2 separate regions (A and B) but products are stored in one warehouse.

What I've done currently works, but is slow. 10 years, 200 tests and 25,000 products need 10 seconds to run.

The setup:

```
library(data.table)

n_products <- 25000
n_years <- 10
n_tests <- 200

pct_error <- 2
A_fcst <- runif(n_years, min = 1, max = 8)
B_fcst <- runif(n_years, min = 3, max = 6)
```

Populate initial DT and matrices:

```
yearly_demand_A <- matrix(0, n_years, n_tests)
yearly_demand_B <- matrix(0, n_years, n_tests)

for (i in 1:n_years){
  yearly_demand_A[i,] <- rnorm(n_tests, A_fcst[i], pct_error*sqrt(i))
  yearly_demand_B[i,] <- rnorm(n_tests, B_fcst[i], pct_error*sqrt(i))
}

yearly_pallets <- matrix(0, n_years, n_tests)

demand_x_pallets <- data.table(prod_code = 1:n_products, stock_qty = as.integer(runif(n_products,1,100)), pallet_qty = as.integer(runif(n_products,10,30)), demand_A = runif(n_products,1,40), demand_B = runif(n_products,1,40))
demand_x_pallets[,pallets := ceiling(stock_qty/pallet_qty)]
demand_x_pallets[,demand := demand_A + demand_B]

for (i in 1:n_tests){
  yearly_pallets[1:n_years,i] <- number_of_pallets(yearly_demand_A[1:n_years,i], yearly_demand_B[1:n_years,i], demand_x_pallets)
}
```

And the function itself:

```
number_of_pallets <- function(fcst_A,fcst_B,d_x_p,year=0){
  pallets <- vector("double",n_years)
  new_profile <- copy(d_x_p)    #if I don't create a copy, the same DT is passed and number of pallets compunds
  if (year == 0){               #if function called without year argument call it recursively
    for(i in 1:(n_years)){
      new_profile <- number_of_pallets(fcst_A[[i]],fcst_B[[i]],new_profile,i)
      pallets[i] <- new_profile[,sum(pallets)]
    }
  }
  else{                         #calculate demand and pallet count for each product each year
    d_x_p[,demand_A := demand_A * (100+fcst_A) / 100]
    d_x_p[,demand_B := demand_B * (100+fcst_B) / 100]
    d_x_p[,new_Dmnd := demand_A + demand_B]
    d_x_p[,Dmnd_change := ifelse(demand==0,1,new_Dmnd/demand)]
    d_x_p[,stock_qty := stock_qty * Dmnd_change]
    d_x_p[,pallets := ceiling(stock_qty/pallet_qty)]
    d_x_p[,demand := new_Dmnd]
    return(d_x_p)
  }
  return(pallets)
}
```

Initially, I thought that copying the DT might be the reason for making it slow, but removing the line in the function, apart from making it not working properly, doesn't make any difference. This is the best I came up so far after few miserable failures, but I'm completely stuck now.

Any pointers on how to tackle it differently would be greatly appreciated.